# What is the use of Homogeneous vectors in Computer Vision?

Tags: computer-vision, homogenous-transformation

I am a beginner in Computer Vision and I am not sure why homogeneous vectors are used in Computer Vision? I have read a few posts but I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 1):

Homogeneous coordinates allow you to express various coordinate transformations (rigid, affine, projective) as a multiplication by a single matrix. These transformations occur in computer vision all the time: image registration or stitching, stereo rectification, 3D reconstruction, object detection, etc.